# How to convert a string value of numbers into a telephone format inside an anchor tag?

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a dynamic string value of numbers which might be changed in the future that's why I don't want to hard code it.

```
<?php $telephone = (03) 1234 5678; // this number displays on the frontend only ?>

<a href="tel:+61-3-1234-5678"><?php echo $telephone; ?></a>
```

So I want to change/format the value from "(03) 1234 5678" to "tel:+61-3-1234-5678".
How can I properly achieve this?

Comment: Use a library for this sort of thing. They do all the heavy lifting for you. https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php https://github.com/brick/phonenumber

Comment: I did not DV you, but the reasons you were DV'd is that you didn't show any effort in attempting to solve your own problem. Also, the code you did provided (`$telephone = (03) 1234 5678;`) is not valid PHP so we could not reliably reproduce this. Lastly, but most importantly, you did not provide any clear requirements besides showing a sample output.  Because of these reasons, the solution provided below will quickly fall short if the phone number changes format even slightly (Try using 2 spaces `$phone ="(03) 1234  5678";`).

Comment: I see. I was in a hurry lately that's why I didn't check my code clearly and produce a more concise explanation. And you're right about the extra spaces, the first solution below will surely fail. I think I need to revise this or maybe try your given links for the solution. Thanks, @waterloomatt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explode your string on the basis of space and after that str_replace to remove (,) and 0 then you find out follow output.this code for php.

```
    $str="tel:+61-";
    $phone ="(03) 1234 5678";
    $string=explode(" ",$phone);
    $strone=str_replace("(","",$string[0]);
    $strone=str_replace(")","",$strone);
    $strone=str_replace("0","",$strone);
    print_r($str.$strone."-".$string[1]."-".$string[2]);
    exit;
```

Comment: That's so nice of yours! Thanks for the correct answer and for your effort. :)

Comment: Hello Babbal, as what the other commenter mentioned above about extra spaces that might be mistyped. Do you think we can have a quick revision of your solution?

Comment: I've added **trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $number));** to remove extra spaces in the string. I think this totally solved my problem.